# Why does $\tan(50) = \frac{1}{\tan(40)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I notice that $50 + 40 = 90$, so it might have something to do with the complementary functions (thats what comes to mind) it $\sin(90 - x) = \cos(x) $. However, $\tan(90 - x) = \cot(x)$. When I put the title question in the calculator it is indeed true but I don't understand why. Could someone explain?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand why $\tan(90^{\circ}-x)=\cot x$ is true?

Comment: Just plug in $x=40$ into the equation you gave. $tan(90-40) = cot(40)$ so $tan(50) = cot(40)$. By definition $cot(40)=\frac{1}{tan(40)}$. So we have $tan(50) = \frac{1}{tan(40)}$.

Comment: Consider the geometric meaning of $\sin, \cos, \tan, \cot$, and that the sum of interior angles of a triangle is $180^\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tan50=\frac1{\cot50}=\frac1{\tan40}$

Answer (score 5):

Consider a triangle with angles $40^\circ$, $50^\circ$, and $90^\circ$; let $a, b, c$ respectively be the length of the sides opposite these angles (for example, $c$ is the hypotenuse).

Note that $\tan(50^\circ)$ is defined to be $\frac{b}{a}$, i.e. the length of opposite side divided by the length of the adjacent (non-hypotenuse) side.

Note also that $\tan(40^\circ)$ is defined to be $\frac{a}{b}$, for much the same reason. Now the side $a$ is opposite the $40^\circ$ angle, and the side $b$ is adjacent.

Now note that $\tan(50^\circ) \times \tan(40^\circ) = \frac{b}{a} \times \frac{a}{b} = 1$, and so, dividing both sides by $\tan(40^\circ)$,
$$\tan(50^\circ) = \frac{1}{\tan(40^\circ)}.$$

This holds more generally too. If we have an angle of $\theta < 90^\circ$ in a right-angled triangle, then $90 - \theta^\circ$ is the other angle. Following the same logic, we see that
$$\tan(90 - \theta^\circ) = \frac{1}{\tan(\theta^\circ)}.$$